# Как выровнить article по правому краю

Tags: html

подскажите пожалуйста, как блоки   у который id равен ВходящееСообщение и ИсходящееСообщение сдвинуть до конца вправо и влево соответсвенно

```css
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            background: #FBF9EC;
        }

        body {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 4px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #B3AC86;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }

        .chatbox {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow: hidden;
            box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .28);
            vertical-align: sub;
        }

        .chat-window {
            flex: auto;
            max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
            overflow: auto;
            vertical-align: sub;
        }

        .chat-input {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            height: 60px;
            background: #40434e;
            border-top: 1px solid #2671ff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .28);
        }

        .chat-input input {
            height: 59px;
            line-height: 60px;
            outline: 0 none;
            border: none;
            width: calc(100% - 60px);
            color: white;
            text-indent: 10px;
            font-size: 12pt;
            padding: 0;
            background: #40434e;
        }

        .chat-input button {
            float: right;
            outline: 0 none;
            border: none;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 2px 0 0 0;
            margin: 10px;
            transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
        }

        .chat-input input[good] + button {
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
            background: #2671ff;
        }

        .chat-input input[good] + button:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        }

        .chat-input input[good] + button path {
            fill: white;
        }
        
        .msg-container {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 0 10px 0;
            padding: 0;
            vertical-align: sub;
        }

        .msg-box {
            display: flex;
            background: #5b5e6c;
            padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
            max-width: 80%;
            width: auto;
            float: left;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
        }

        .user-img {
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            background: #2671ff;
            margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        }

        .flr {
            flex: 1 0 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: calc(100% - 50px);
        }

        .messages {
            flex: 1 0 auto;
        }

        .msg {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 11pt;
            line-height: 13pt;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
            margin: 0 0 4px 0;
        }

        .msg:first-of-type {
            margin-top: 8px;
        }

        .timestamp {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .38);
            font-size: 8pt;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .username {
            margin-right: 3px;
        }

        .posttime {
            margin-left: 3px;
        }

        .msg-self .msg-box {
            border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
            background: #00a6ff;
            float: right;
        }

        .msg-self .user-img {
            margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }

        .msg-self .msg {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .msg-self .timestamp {
            text-align: right;
        }
```

```html
<section class="chat-window">

        <article class="msg-container msg-remote" id="ВходящееСообщение">
            <div class="msg-box">
                <img class="user-img" id="user-0" src="//gravatar.com/avatar/00034587632094500000000000000000?d=retro">
                <div class="flr">
                    <div class="messages">
                        <p class="msg" id="Сообщение">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <span class="timestamp"><span class="username">Name</span>•<span
                            class="posttime">3 minutes ago</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    <article class="msg-container msg-self" id="ИсходящееСообщение">
        <div class="msg-box">


            <div class="flr">


                <div class="messages">


                    <p class="msg" id="Сообщение">
                        Таким образом,</p>


                </div>
                <span class="timestamp"><span class="username">Name</span>•<span
                        class="posttime">2 minutes ago</span></span>
            </div>
            <img class="user-img" id="user-0" src=""></div>
    </article>
</section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.chat-window {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 80vw;
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек)

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов, пожалуйста) если помогло - поставьте галочку на ответе, чтобы отметить его, как правильный